# Как обратится к элементу через несколько класов js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно получить текст тега `а` и присвоить классу `size`, а также получить путь к картинке:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-catalog-block-item" style="background: url(img/grey.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size: cover">
</div>
<li class="size-category active" data-id="2">
  <a href="#">S</a>
</li>
<p class="size"></p>
<img class="imagebox" src="">
<script>
  var size = $(".size-category .active a").text();
  $(".size").text(size);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селектор `.size-category.active` - без пробела.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-catalog-block-item" style="background: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png) center no-repeat; background-size: cover">Test Test Test
</div>
<li class="size-category active" data-id="2">
  <a href="#">S</a>
</li>
<p class="size"></p>
<img class="imagebox" src="about:blank" />
<script>
  var style = getComputedStyle($(".img-catalog-block-item")[0]);
  var imgSrc = style.backgroundImage.replace('url(\"', '').replace('\")', '');
  $(".imagebox").attr("src", imgSrc);
  var size = $(".size-category.active a").text();
  $(".size").text(size);
</script>
```

Comment: как можно получить путь к картинке и присвоить imageblock?

Comment: @Alexander, `let imgSrc = $(this).find('.imagebox').attr('src');`, для присвоения `$(this).find('.imagebox').addClass('imageblock');`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Спасибо, а как присвоить img с классом imageblock?

Comment: @Alexander О какой картинке речь? Из `style="background: url(img/grey.jpg)`?

Comment: @Igor да, картинка фона

Comment: @Alexander  в ответе

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, а как присвоить imagebox в src полученный путь к картинке

Comment: @Alexander в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
 document.querySelector('li.size-category > a');
```

`>` тут указывает, что `<a>` непосредственный потомок `<li>`

```html
<li class="size-category active" data-id="2">
    <a href="#">S</a>
</li>

<script>
let a = document.querySelector('li.size-category.active > a');
console.log(a)
</script>
```

Или так :

```html
<li class="size-category active" data-id="2">
    <a href="#">S</a>
</li>

<script>
let a = document.querySelector('li.size-category.active  a');
console.log(a)
</script>
```

Comment: а как можно получить путь к картинке?

Comment: И мне нужно присвоить значение именно size-category active

Comment: @Alexander дополнил овет